# Auto sort script sorting different sheets by different columns

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script, sorting

I have a master sheet where data is entered.
I would like the other sheets in the book (which currently auto-populate from the master sheet) to sort (in descending order) by their respective column in the master sheet.
For example: Sheet "Alice" sorts by column "Alice" from the master sheet, sheet "Bernie" sorts by column "Bernie from the master sheet, etc.

So if my "Master" sheet is

```
 Class      Alice      Bernie      Courtney
 Math         1          2            
 English      3          1            2
 Science      2          3            1
```

Then sheet "Alice" would auto-sort to:

```
 Class      Alice      Bernie      Courtney
 English      3          1            2
 Science      2          3            1
 Math         1          2
```

And sheet "Bernice" would auto-sort to:

```
 Class      Alice      Bernie      Courtney
 Science      2          3            1
 Math         1          2            
 English      3          1            2
```

And sheet "Courtney" would auto-sort to

```
 Class      Alice      Bernie      Courtney
 English      3          1            2
 Science      2          3            1
 Math         1          2
```

(Please note each sheet has the same values for each entry in the matrix--the order of the rows is simply being rearranged according to which column the sheet is meant to sort by.)

Answer (score 1):

Try

Alice! A1:

```
 =SORT('Master'!A1:D4,2,0)
```

Bernice! A1:

```
 =SORT('Master'!A1:D4,3,0)
```

and so on..

Comment: This answer avoids writing a custom script. Only use scripts as a last resort n.n